# How do i write list data to existing xlsx file in particular column without overwriting using java

Tags: java, excel

I have two 'xlsx' files 'sss.xlsx' and 'abc.xlsx'.

In 'sss.xlsx' file there are some Headers (columns only, doesn't contain any data) and in 'abc.xlsx' file there is data.

I wants to copy data from 'abc' file to 'sss' file column by column by checking column names. If column name matches then copy that column data to "sss.xlsx"
In same column (keep column as it is given in sss file).

I tried with below code. I am able to write but while writing header gets deleted. I am not getting where I went wrong.

Code:

```
public class Read {
     private static int flag;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        //Create blank workbook
          HSSFWorkbook workbook1 = new HSSFWorkbook();
          //Create a blank sheet
          HSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook1.createSheet(
          "  Info ");

         ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
         Read read = new Read();

         File f2 = new File("sss.xlsx");
         FileInputStream ios2 = new FileInputStream(f2);
         XSSFWorkbook workbook2 = new XSSFWorkbook(ios2);

         XSSFSheet sheet2 = workbook2.getSheetAt(0);
         int noOfColumns = sheet2.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
         System.out.println(noOfColumns);
         //String temp2=f.getSheet();

         Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet2.iterator();
         while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
              Row row = rowIterator.next();
              Iterator <Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
              while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell1 = cellIterator.next();
                String temp2=cell1.getStringCellValue().toString();
                System.out.print(cell1.getStringCellValue() + "\n");

         lst = read.extractExcelContentByColumnIndex(temp2);

         File f3 = new File("sss.xlsx");
         FileInputStream ios = new FileInputStream(f3);
         XSSFWorkbook workbook3 = new XSSFWorkbook(ios);
       String  temp1=f3.getName();
       //String colName="Mob No";
         XSSFSheet sheet3 = workbook3.getSheetAt(0);
         //String temp2=f.getSheet();
         int columnIndex1=0;
         Iterator<Row> rowIterator3 = sheet3.iterator();
         //columndata =  new ArrayList<String>();

         while (rowIterator3.hasNext()) {

             Row row3 = rowIterator3.next();

             Iterator<Cell> cellIterator3 = row3.cellIterator();
        while (cellIterator3.hasNext()) {

         Cell cell3 = cellIterator3.next();
         String temp5=cell3.getStringCellValue().toString();
         //System.out.println(temp);
         if(temp5.equals(temp2)){
              columnIndex1 = cell1.getColumnIndex();

             System.out.println(columnIndex1);
             flag=1;
             break;
         }
             }
             if(flag==1)
             {
                 flag = 0;
                 break;

             }

         }
         while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

             Row row6 = rowIterator.next();
            // System.out.println(row.getRowNum());
             Iterator<Cell> cellIterator6 = row6.cellIterator();
             while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                   Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                 if(row.getRowNum() > 0){ //To filter column headings
                     if(cell.getColumnIndex() == columnIndex1){// To match column index

                       //  }

                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         for(int RowNum=0; RowNum<lst.size();RowNum++){

              HSSFRow row1 = spreadsheet.createRow(RowNum+1);

                  HSSFCell cell6 = row1.createCell(columnIndex1);

                  cell6.setCellValue(lst.get(RowNum).toString());

               }

             }

          //Write the workbook in file system
         FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("sss.xlsx"));
         // System.out.println(lst);
         workbook1.write(out);
         out.close();
     }
    }

    public  ArrayList<String> extractExcelContentByColumnIndex( String colName)
     {
            ArrayList<String> columndata = null;
            int columnIndex= 0;
            int flag=0;
            try {
                File f = new File("abc.xlsx");

                FileInputStream ios = new FileInputStream(f);
                XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(ios);
              String  temp1=f.getName();

                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                //String temp2=f.getSheet();
                Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
                columndata =  new ArrayList<String>();

                while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

                    Row row = rowIterator.next();

                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
               while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                Cell cell1 = cellIterator.next();
                String temp=cell1.getStringCellValue().toString();
                //System.out.println(temp);
                if(temp.equals(colName)){
                    columnIndex=cell1.getColumnIndex();
                    flag=1;
                    break;
                }
                    }
                    if(flag==1)
                    {
                        flag = 0;
                        break;

                    }

                }
                while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

                    Row row = rowIterator.next();
                   // System.out.println(row.getRowNum());
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                          Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                        if(row.getRowNum() > -1){ //To filter column headings
                            if(cell.getColumnIndex() == columnIndex){// To match column index
                                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:

                                    columndata.add(cell.getNumericCellValue()+"");
                                    break;
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:

                                    columndata.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                                    break;

                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                ios.close();

                System.out.println(colName);
                for(String ele : columndata)
                {

                System.out.println(ele);

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return columndata;

        }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes i have added it